# How to Print array value on the view file in ionic Framework

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I am Fresher in ionic & Angular Mobile Application. I am developing dummy

Application  using ionic framework. I want to print array on view file.Actually my

App Working Properly no issue occure. But according to my codeigniter experince

We Can print the array on view file using print_r. How I can see the what value

In The array which is passed on the view file.

`enter code here`

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is showing the proper list no problem in this code. like Codeigniter if I

Want to check the what value into **playlists we easily print_r(playlists)**;

How can I see what data into **playlists in ionic Framework.**

Is It Possiable?

Comment: php is not related here. print_r is php's function, it has nothing to do with ionic which is purely client-side framework. don't confuse server-side and client-side

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in the `controller` add `console.log($scope.playlists)`. Then 2 things can be done assuming you are running using command line:

- Ionic is served from using the following command (Can set it up in [ionic lab app](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPzbTs3o3MAhWEDxoKHUsnD4kQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flab.ionic.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNHU1gKLv9gZCD9Wwy63_w7N64H2_Q&sig2=d_tra00DPKIaMY0AKjncAg) as well): `ionic serve -c` OR `ionic serve --lab -c`  - This enables console logging.
  Sometimes in ionic it only shows object and not the underlying.
- F12 in chrome top open dev tools and select Console. Serve ionic again as inidicated above. This will show you the objects and children. 
  Best option in most cases

**Update**

[This article explain in Ionic debugging on chrome dev tools in detail](http://mcgivery.com/debugging-ionic-apps-chrome-developer-tools/). Andrew McGivery blogs has vast resources on the intricacies of Ionic.

Comment: means we can use console.log in controller not in view file.is it right.

Comment: As far as I know yes. Using console.log() you should also be able to loop through the playlists - in the controller and view all the outputs in the dev tool Console tab or in command line.